# efficient way to find the most recent entry in another dataframe for each entry of a dataframe indexed by datetime in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, and both of them are indexed by datetime.
for example, the dataframe 1 is something below:

```
|date            |  value |
+----------------+--------+
|2021-11-11 09:00|    1   |
|2021-11-11 10:00|    1   |
|2021-11-12 11:00|    2   |
|2021-11-14 09:00|    2   |
|2021-11-15 09:30|    3   |
```

and the dataframe 2 looks like:

```
|date            |  value |
+----------------+--------+
|2021-11-10 11:00|    2   |
|2021-11-11 09:30|    3   |
|2021-11-12 12:00|    4   |
|2021-11-13 09:50|    2   |
|2021-11-15 10:30|    3   |
```

For each entry in dataframe 1, I want to find the most recent one entry in dataframe 2, and create a new column in dataframe 1 to setup the relationship between the two dataframes.

To make it more clearly, the expected results should look like below.

```
|date            |  value |    df2_index   |
+----------------+--------+----------------|
|2021-11-11 09:00|    1   |2021-11-10 11:00|
|2021-11-11 10:00|    1   |2021-11-11 09:30|
|2021-11-12 11:00|    2   |2021-11-11 09:30|
|2021-11-14 09:00|    2   |2021-11-13 09:50|
|2021-11-15 09:30|    3   |2021-11-13 09:50|
```

For the first entry in dataframe 1, `2021-11-11 09:00`'s most recent one is `2021-11-10 11:00`, and the third entry `2021-11-12 11:00`'s most recent one which means the largest timestamp that do not exceed `2021-11-12 11:00` in dataframe 2 is the `2021-11-11 09:30`.

Is there any pandas method that could implement this function efficiently?

Great thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pandas `merge_asof` should suffice :

```py
pd.merge_asof(df1, df2.assign(df2_index = df2.date), on = 'date')

                 date  value_x  value_y           df2_index
0 2021-11-11 09:00:00        1        2 2021-11-10 11:00:00
1 2021-11-11 10:00:00        1        3 2021-11-11 09:30:00
2 2021-11-12 11:00:00        2        3 2021-11-11 09:30:00
3 2021-11-14 09:00:00        2        2 2021-11-13 09:50:00
4 2021-11-15 09:30:00        3        2 2021-11-13 09:50:00
```