# Finding the smallest difference with the values in another dataframe in the same category for each entry using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge

suppose I have the following two dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame()

df1['group'] = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b']

df1['value'] = [1, 0, 1, 4]

df2 = pd.DataFrame()

df2['group'] = ['a', 'a', 'b']

df2['value'] = [2, 4, 3]
```

For each value in df1, I want to be able to identify its smallest difference with the values in the same group ('a' or 'b') in df2.

For example, for first entry with group 'a' and value 1 in df1, I want to find its smallest difference with the values in group 'a' in df2. In this case, the cloest number is 2 so the smallest difference is 1.

Overall, the desired output is:

`df['smallest_diff'] = [1, 2, 2, 1]`

Thank you!

(I can only think of a dumb way to cross match all values in the same group between df1 and df2 using merge. And I am trying to find an efficient way.)

I found a post which is trying to find the closest date in another dataframe.
[efficient way to find the most recent entry in another dataframe for each entry of a dataframe indexed by datetime in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73767537/efficient-way-to-find-the-most-recent-entry-in-another-dataframe-for-each-entry)

This is close to what I want, only that I need to find the closest value in the same group.

Comment: `pd.merge_asof`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code**

make val2 column(mean nearest value in df2)

& make diff columns(mean |value - val2|)

```
out = (pd.merge_asof(df1.assign(index=df1.index).sort_values('value'), 
                     df2.sort_values('value').assign(val2=df2['value']), 
                     on='value', by='group', direction='nearest')
         .assign(diff=lambda x: x['value'].sub(x['val2']).abs())
         .set_index('index').sort_index())
```

`out` :

```
    group   value   val2    diff
index               
0   a       1       2       1
1   a       0       2       2
2   b       1       3       2
3   b       4       3       1
```

get your desired output

```
out['diff']
```

```
0    1
1    2
2    2
3    1
Name: diff, dtype: int64
```